# Get Feed from event of page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to access all events from my page (using manage_pages). Then, for certain events (id's in an array) I need to access the feed and get the pictures.

I already constructed this link:

https://graph.facebook.com/[pageid]/events?fields=feed&access_token=[access_token_from_page]

which is fine. But I was wondering if I could somehow specify the IDs of the events in the url? And maybe also saying I just want photos?

I'm looking for a way to minimalize the response.

Thanks!

Comment: seems I was to hasty. My access_token isn't sufficient enough to get all the data from the post. I just see the public data. Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?
Also, should I refresh (do the POST thing) the page access token everytime? Or does it have a certain life span?

Comment: alright, just figured that I need a personal access token.